# PHP: display input sequence in blocks of 25 letters and only 75 letters per line

Tags: php, html

I am learning PHP myself so i can use in University.  I am practising exercises, however this has been too hard for me.  A user will input random sequence into a form.. lets call this $_POST ['query'].  I want to display this $_POST ['query'] like below:

> Title
>
> > 1  QDGDAAKGEK EFNKCKACHM IQAPDGTDII KGGKTGPNLY GVVGRKIASE
> >
> > > 76  EGFKYGEGIL EVAEKNPDLT WTEADLIEYV TDPKPWLVKM TDDKGAKTKM
> > >
> > > > 151  TFKMGKNQAD VVAFLAQNSP DAGGDGEAA

Any help would be much appreciated.  Thanks:)

Comment: its unclear what you are asking, how is it supposed to split them etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [chunk_split](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.chunk-split.php) and [explode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php). That, in combination with a basic for-loop should get you started.

Answer (score 0):

You should iterate through the string, like below.

```
for($i = 0; $i < strlen($string); $i++) {
    echo $string[$i] . "\n";
}
```

Then you can control flow with if($i % $n) which will be false for every $n:th iteration.